# WPF ContextMenu Closed Event, how to differentiate closing method

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

Inside my Canvas I have a ContextMenu with the expected functionality of closing when you select an option in the menu, or when you click outside of it. However I want my program to respond differently based on which of those methods was used to close the ContextMenu. From what I can tell the Closed Event on the ContextMenu fires in both scenarios. Is there any way to make that distinction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please explain more about problem?
I think it's obvious that you have to scenario. 1: click on ContexMenu options you created which will invoke an event fore sure and clicking outside it which will cancel the context Menu. by the way I made an answer base on my understanding of you problem. If I got it wrong please tell me.

The bellow code is Just a demo code , The logic Behind it is important.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Windows Load event
    private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Very Important Because by default it's null
        this.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();

        // Making 3 sample Menu Item for ContextMenu
        MenuItem firstMenuItem = new MenuItem()
        {
            Header = "FirsMenu"
        };

        //1st of three way to give event to Controls. 
        // Giving click Event to firstMenuItem to seprate it's click behavior from Other Menu Items
        firstMenuItem.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            // if Tag be Null on context Menu closing it's get that non of item selected so the click must be out side or lost focused
            this.ContextMenu.Tag = 1;
            MessageBox.Show("First Menu Clicked");
        };

        MenuItem secondMenuItem = new MenuItem()
        {
            Header = "SecondMenu"
        };

        //2nd of three way to give event to Controls. 
        // Giving click Event to secondMenuItem to seprate it's click behavior from Other Menu Items
        secondMenuItem.Click += delegate
        {
            // if Tag be Null on context Menu closing it's get that non of item selected so the click must be out side or lost focused
            this.ContextMenu.Tag = 1;
            MessageBox.Show("Second Menu Clicked");
        };

        MenuItem thirdMenuItem = new MenuItem()
        {
            Header = "ThirdMenu"
        };

        //3rd of three way to give event to Controls. 
        // Giving click Event to thirdMenuItem to seprate it's click behavior from Other Menu Items
        thirdMenuItem.Click += ThirdMenuOnClick;

        this.ContextMenu.Items.Add(firstMenuItem);
        this.ContextMenu.Items.Add(secondMenuItem);
        this.ContextMenu.Items.Add(thirdMenuItem);

        this.ContextMenu.Closed += ContextMenuOnClosed;
    }

    private void ThirdMenuOnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if Tag be Null on context Menu closing it's get that non of item selected so the click must be out side or lost focused
        this.ContextMenu.Tag = 1;
        MessageBox.Show("Third Menu Clicked");
    }

    // Event for opening contextmenu on right mouse button click 
    private void MainWindow_OnMouseRightButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void ContextMenuOnClosed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // if null means click must be out side or lost focused
        if (((ContextMenu)sender).Tag == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You Clicked OutSide");
        }

        // very Importnt code , because it will reset the context menu tag logically
        ((ContextMenu)sender).Tag = null;
    }

}
```

Wish You bests, Heydar.